# Creating a Dropdown list by fetching data from backend

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have created a course container and I want to populate the options by fetching them from the backend

(URL: https://ffcc-app.herokuapp.com/get/courses)

```html
<div class="container">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
        <h2>Course 1</h2>
        <div class="select-box">
          <div class="options-container">
            <select class="option" id="one">
              <option value="">Select a course.. </option>
              
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="selected">
            Select Courses
          </div>
          <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Also when I type any character in the search box it should filter the options.
Can someone help me on how to fetch the data from the URL to populate the options list?

PS: I am familiar with Fetch API for fetching the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
let result = {};
let allCourses = {};

function filterCourses() {
  var filter = document.getElementById("inputFilter").value;
  result.courses = allCourses.courses.filter(x => x.title.includes(filter))
  let select = document.getElementById("one");
  
  while (select.firstChild) {
        select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < result.courses.length; i++){
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = result.courses[i]._id;
        option.text = result.courses[i].title;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}

async function getCourses() {
    let url = 'users.json';
    try {
        let res = await fetch("https://ffcc-app.herokuapp.com/get/courses");
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function renderCourses() {
    allCourses = await getCourses();
    result = Object.assign({}, allCourses);
    let select = document.getElementById("one");
    for (let i = 0; i < result.courses.length; i++){
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = result.courses[i]._id;
        option.text = result.courses[i].title;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}

renderCourses()
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
            <h2>Course 1</h2>
            <div class="select-box">
              <div class="options-container">
                <select class="option" id="one">
                  <option value="">Select a course.. </option>
                  
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="selected">
                Select Courses
              </div>
              <div class="search-box">
                <input type="text" id="inputFilter" placeholder="Search..." onchange="filterCourses()"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Explanation: after loaded all the courses, I made an option for each course (with `_id` as option value and `title` as option text). This is made by function `renderCourses`.

Then the `filterCourses` function: basically it takes the value from input and looks for an option that contains what you typed in input. If you clean the input, function returns all the courses.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works just fine. I want to make the search case insensitive, so can u tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @SidharthMishra it's just necessary to use `toUpperCase`. So: `allCourses.courses.filter(x => x.title.toUpperCase().includes(filter.toUpperCase()))`

Comment: Yep got it! I guess it works for both either uppercase or lowercase right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your api, create a function to manipulate your DOM, pass the data to this function so that it renders the content inside the select tag.

This is just for the select tag.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.option')

fetch('https://ffcc-app.herokuapp.com/get/courses')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.courses.forEach(course => render(course))
  });

function render(course) {
  const opt = document.createElement('option')
  opt.value = course.title
  const content = document.createTextNode(`${course.title}`)
  opt.appendChild(content)
  select.appendChild(opt)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
        <h2>Course 1</h2>
        <div class="select-box">
          <div class="options-container">
            <select class="option" id="one">
              <option value="">Select a course.. </option>
              
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="selected">
            Select Courses
          </div>
          <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And the filter function? =)